# Python/C#, Reading File into Byte Array - Not Quite the Same Result

Tags: c#, python, encoding, arrays

I'm attempting to read a file and process it in both C# and IronPython, but I'm running into a slight problem.

When I read the file in either language, I get a byte array that's ***almost*** identical, but not quite.

For instance, the array has 1552 bytes. They're all the same except for one thing. Any time the value "10" appears in the Python implementation, the value "13" appears in the C# implementation. Aside from that, all other bytes are the same.

Here's roughly what I'm doing to get the bytes:

Python:

```
f = open('C:\myfile.blah')
contents = f.read()
bytes = bytearray(contents, 'cp1252')
```

C#:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\myfile.blah");
```

Perhaps I'm choosing the wrong encoding? Though I wouldn't think so, since the Python implementation behaves as I would expect and processes the file successfully.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't know python) But it looks like you need to pass the `'rb'` flag:

```
open('C:\myfile.blah', 'rb')
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. **Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written.**

- Note that the values `10` and `13` give clues as to what the problem is:
  `Line feed` is **10** in decimal and `Carriage return` is **13** in decimal.

Comment: Thanks! This was absolutely what was wrong. Though, now I've run into a similar, but not the same, issue. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908450/c-sharp-file-readallbytes-gives-seemingly-incorrect-values)

Any chance you've got the magic fix for that one, too? I'm considering the python-read file to be the "correct" arrangement of bytes.

Comment: Not a complete answer - not helpful